# I am not able to bundle install my new app in Rails it show me following error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My s/w version are:

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
Rails -v 4.2.5
windows 10
gem -v 2.4.5.1
```

Comment: many time but it gives error

Comment: What error do you get when you run `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` (not `bundle install`)?

Comment: Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Comment: windows 10 – this is the problem. Use Ubuntu as a separate OS or run it via Vagrant, otherwise you'll have many problems with gems in the future.

Comment: yes, due to so much issues its must to change os.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler 1.5.0 has a bug where it doesn't recognize default gems as [referenced here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1806).

The solution was to update to bundler 1.5.1 using `gem install bundler -v '= 1.5.1'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Windows but you could try to install [this GMP package](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/). As suggested on the json Github issues [page](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/259), people on linux should install the package below:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

And what it seems is that package for Windows has a similar dll which could resolve your problem.

There are known issues with the gem `json 1.8.3` and `ruby 2.2.3` listed in thoses issues [#259](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/259) and [#229](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229)